# how to assess tuples in a list in python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, tuples

I have 4 people that are all at a different location. I suppose these should be tuples in a list?

```
People=[(5,0),(4,3),(5,2),(8,3)]
```

Person 1 is on `x=5` and `y=0`, if you'd consider it a 2D grid, etc.

There's a car at `(8,4)`

I have created a code that calculates to which person the car is closest by first splitting up the x and y coordinates, putting those in a list, and then looping over this list to calculate the cost for each:

```
for i in range (4):
    cost=abs((xcar-xpeople[i])+(ycar-people[I])
```

That worked, however, I would like to NOT split up the coordinates first, and asses the tuples in the list one by one, but treat them as a whole. How do I do this?

I hope this is clear!
Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could consider using [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org) library, it makes operations with arrays fast and easy:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> people=np.array([(5,0),(4,3),(5,2),(8,3)])
>>> xcar = np.array((8,4))
>>> abs(people - xcar)
array([[3, 4],
       [4, 1],
       [3, 2],
       [0, 1]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply unpack the tuples whilst iterating over the list:

```
for x, y in People:
    cost = abs((xcar - x) + (ycar - y))
```

Comment: Thanks you! It indeed works! However, I now want the car to pick up the closest person. Meaning that istst's new coordina tes shoudld be (8,3) how does that work? I do not get further than thinking than: closestperson=cost.index(min(cost))  car[0]=x[closestperson] car[1]=y[closestperson], this doesn't work and I guess there should be an easier way to do it right?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> People=[(5,0),(4,3),(5,2),(8,3)]
>>> car=(8,4)
>>> from math import hypot
>>> from operator import sub

>>> closest=min(People, key=lambda pos: hypot(*map(sub, pos, car)))

>>> closest
(8, 3)
```

Comment: Note: this actually calculates the distance on a Cartesian plane, while OP does sum of distances in x and y directions.  +1 for reading what OP said rather than what OP did.

Comment: Interesting! I can now append 'closest' to the route list that I created. However, when running the script, the starting location is no longer considered a tuple. I first  used route=[car]   route=list(itertools.chain(*route1)) to get rid of the list in the list, but now it also got rid of the brackets. When running the script I get the answer: [1,2, (), (),()] where the brackets nicely have the right order of closest locations.

Comment: I don't exactly understand. If it's a different problem, do you mind updating your question?

Comment: Dear @Ni. , I am new to actively using stackoverflow, so i do not know how to update, therefore I have created a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41304799/how-do-i-get-data-in-tuples-and-tuples-in-lists

Answer (score 0):

Complex numbers are ordered pairs in disguise.

```
people = [5, 4+3j, 5+2j, 8+3j]
car = 8+4j
costs = [abs(car - person) for person in people]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to import additional libraries (like numpy) and you don't want to do unnecessary operations (like `power` and then the square root) just to calculate the distance, you can do it in plain Python with `enumerate`:

```
People=[(5,0),(4,3),(5,2),(17,10),(8,3)]
car = (8,4)

min_cost = 99999
min_index = -1

for i, coord in enumerate(People):
    cost = abs(car[0] - coord[0]) + (car[1] - coord[1])
    if (min_cost > cost):
        (min_cost, min_index) = (cost, i)

print(People[min_index])
```

This way you also have the index, not just the value, in case you need it later for other operations.